# About function re-compilation each time we call jax.jit

Tags: jax

I am a newbie to `jax`. When I'm reading to the documentation, I'm confused about the caching behavior of `jit`.

In the [caching section](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax-101/02-jitting.html#caching), it says that "Avoid calling jax.jit inside loops. Doing that effectively creates a new f at each call, which will get compiled each time instead of reusing the same cached function". However, running the following code only produces one printing side effect:

```
import jax
def unjitted_loop_body(prev_i):
  print("tracing...")
  return prev_i + 1

def g_inner_jitted_poorly(x, n):
  i = 0
  while i < n:
    # Don't do this!
    i = jax.jit(unjitted_loop_body)(i)
  return x + i

g_inner_jitted_poorly(10, 20)
# output:
WARNING:absl:No GPU/TPU found, falling back to CPU. (Set TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0 and rerun for more info.)
tracing...
Out[1]: DeviceArray(30, dtype=int32)
```

The string "tracing..." is only printed once, and it seems that `jit` does not trace the function again.

Is this intended? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your example is behaving as expected; I suspect it may have been referencing an  older version of the docs.

In the current version of the docs you link to the example is slightly different; rather than jit-compiling the function, it jit-compiles a temporary function wrapper:

```py
def g_inner_jitted_partial(x, n):
  i = 0
  while i < n:
    # Don't do this! each time the partial returns
    # a function with different hash
    i = jax.jit(partial(unjitted_loop_body))(i)
  return x + i
```

If you do this, it will cause re-compiles every time, because `partial(unjitted_loop_body)` is a new function object in every loop, and JIT cacheing is based on the id of the function object.

Using the approach in your question is fine, because the function passed to `jit` is a persistent global function, whose id is the same every iteration:

```py
def g_inner_jitted_normal(x, n):
  i = 0
  while i < n:
    # this is OK, since JAX can find the
    # cached, compiled function
    i = jax.jit(unjitted_loop_body)(i)
  return x + i
```